# How to resolve issues with archive app in XCode (App Store app upload)

Tags: ios, upload, certificate

When I archive my app i get some warning: Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)

I found description of this error here: [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933), but i don't any ideas of resolve this issues.

All profile and certificate are valid. But when i create archive i get this warning. And when I using application loader this warning displayed too (and my app upload rejected)

Thanks for response!

My message:

```
Validate /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Wine-gkolwcegooellmdpwekxnxzupkhu/ArchiveIntermediates/Wine/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Wine.app
    cd /Users/user/Desktop/Wine
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Wine-gkolwcegooellmdpwekxnxzupkhu/ArchiveIntermediates/Wine/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Wine.app
2012-01-16 02:11:14.491 Validation[3263:607] *** Warning: Defaulting to the standard codesign tool
warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)
/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Wine-gkolwcegooellmdpwekxnxzupkhu/ArchiveIntermediates/Wine/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Wine.app: valid on disk
/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Wine-gkolwcegooellmdpwekxnxzupkhu/ArchiveIntermediates/Wine/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Wine.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
test-requirement: failed to satisfy code requirement(s)
 - (null)
```

Answer (score 0):

In these situations, the quickest thing to do is delete all your certificates, provisioning profiles, etc and start over. Generate a CSR from keychain access, get your developer certificate, and generate/download your provisioning profiles (don't forget about your distribution profile).

After that open the provisioning profiles to get them in organizer. Then go into your target's build settings and set the correct code signing identity values.

Organizer should tell you if there are any problems with your provisioning profile after you add it.

Comment: I should start with developer certificate or i can start to upload my app to app strore using distribution certificate only?

Comment: You're going to need the developer certificate in order to run it on your device in the future so it makes sense to take care of it all now.